# Simple inequality with Expectations

Tags: probability, expected-value

How do I show that:
$$
E[(X − E[X] + Y − E[Y])]^2] \leq E[2(X − E[X])^2 + 2(Y − E[Y])^2]
$$

Comment: what is $B$? also, there are too many brackets.

Comment: @Targon you are right, please excuse me for the B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality is equivalent to showing
$$
\text{Var}(X+Y)\leq 2\text{Var}(X)+2\text{Var}(Y)\tag{1}
$$
Note that
$$
\text{Var}(X+Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)+2\text{Cov}(X,Y)
$$
whence (1) is equivalent to showing 
$$
\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)
-2\text{Cov(X,Y)}\geq 0.$$
But this is clear since 
$$
\text{Var}(X-Y)=\text{Var}(X)+\text{Var}(Y)-2\text{Cov}(X,Y)
$$
and variance is always non-negative.